# How we can highlight first item of a ClistCtrl which is created in ICON format?

Tags: c++, mfc

How we can highlight first item of a ClistCtrl which is created in ICON format? I want to highlight first item default.

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .. this is not code generator and homework creator..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
CListCtrl::SetItemState(0,LVIS_SELECTED|LVIS_FOCUSED,LVIS_SELECTED|LVIS_FOCUSED);
```

You find all Infos about such things in the MSDN.

Comment: Thanks sir.But i am using thread there because of that maybe it is not working.

Comment: @RaisShaikh: The first rule of multithreading for GUIs is: Do not use multithreading in a GUI.